# What are the important effects of studying logic?

Tags: logic

I'm working on my assignment in Logic and I'm having a hard time answering this question maybe because my insights about the subject isn't enough because we're just getting started, So can you please give me some insights about Logic and an example of important effects of studying logic for me to have an idea on answering the question.

Comment: Welcome to Philosophy.SE! Here's a related question: http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/24541/2953 -- also, perhaps you could elaborate on "important *for what*" - important to find a job later, important in the study of philosophy, important in ethics specifically, etc. From what perspective are you looking at the subject? And, what ideas do you already have? Please [edit] your question to provide a bit more context.

Comment: Sir I just want you to give me one example of important effect of studying logic because we are required to give 10 and I don't have any idea yet about logic.

Comment: Important effect .. for anything? For example, saying "Studying logic helps your understanding of boolean algebra which is needed for processor design" would be okay? In that case, have a look at the related question I linked to before.

Comment: No 1 for me would be that by studying it we learn how to use it, thus to think properly. But it all depends on what you mean by 'studying logic'. It would easy to design a course that doers not have ten important effects.

Comment: How can the study of logic help a teacher during the training course

Comment: Logic is the formalisation of intuitive tools we used. This awareness helps us push further development of what we mean by "logic" which in turn pushes the number of available tools we have at our calculation-al disposal as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logic is applied in many different fields, for example:

- Mathematics
- Computing Science
- Electrical Engineering

On a very low level it is needed to understand proof methods such as:

- Modus ponens / tollens
- Case distinctions
- Proof by contradiction

It can also be used to prove basic theorems using truth tables.

But most importantly, **learning logic teaches you how to think**. It teaches you what is (in)correct reasoning, to recognise fallacies, to check soundness of arguments, etc. These are things that are needed in a variety of real-life situations, *for example*:

- Talking about science
- Arguments with friends, colleagues, others in general
- Get a better understanding of debates of others (e.g. in politics)

Note: Two years ago there was [a question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/66817/17592) on Electrical Engineering SE which is quite similar to yours, but geared towards digital logic.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to interpret "important" as **it applies to you** personally.
If you learn logic, you will be better prepared to verbally defend yourself.  You will be able to be more effective and efficient at any task you are given.  You will be able to solve complex problems by dividing them into a number of "simpler" problems.  Logic can be applied "across the board," from math, science, language, law, computers, programming, digital circuits,etc.. Logic's applicability is limited, only by the person's ability.

Answer (score 1):

1. It helps you to differentiate between correct and incorrect reasoning.
2. It helps you to do self-judgement before making any comment.
3. It also helps to give answers which will make people rethink their statements well.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Scholars who study Philosophy, hence, Logic think this question easy to be answered, but unfortunately during my study of philosophy and logic I found many of  Scholars of Philosophy, logic and maths have strict minds, not flexible minds. Thus I have some notes demonstrate the role of logic, important effects of studying logic:

- Logic from persistence becomes antilogic, this for Philosophers. Thus Philosophers should use Logic dynamically. We see many scholars of philosophy at many websites of Q/A who can't differentiate between good and bad question, what question fits their conditions and what does not.
- Logician discipline is a talent, not all humans have Logician discipline. Logician discipline means the ability to use Logic even without studying logic. Scholar Logician should some of them have discipline in Logic.
- Mathematics abstraction differs from Logic abstraction, Logic abstraction is higher than Mathematics abstraction.
- Logic is a tool for Philosophy and any science.
- Philosophizing calls Logic and Higher Logic.
- Should be present Meta-logic as Meta-philosophy.
- When we create a Robot that mimics humans in all aspects, then Logic reached its highest.
- Thus Logic is important for Sciences, Humanities.